# Как реализовать Pool в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу реализовать Pool в Unity, но все варианты в сети хранят и возвращают тип GameObject (собственно я и сам такой создавал, там ничего сложного).
Пример:

`Gameobject bullet = PoolManager.GetObject (bulletPrefab.name, shotPoint.position);`

А если мне нужно обратиться к какой-то функции в полученном объекте? В моем случае это вызвать метод `Shot()` у объекта Bullet;

`GetComponent` делать глупо, зачем тогда пул создавать.

Мне нужна подсказка в каком направлении искать решение. Смотрел про обобщения, но то ли это невозможно реализовать, то ли у меня опыта не хватает.

Рассматривал вариант создать в PoolObject свойства со всеми типами, которые нужно хранить в пуле и в зависимости от положения enum делать в Start `GetComponent`. Насколько этот вариант имеет место быть? Вообще хочется что-то поуниверсальнее.

Comment: Покажите необобщенный, обобщить его легко.

Comment: @aepot https://gitlab.com/Nikola94/2d-platformer/-/tree/designer/Assets/Scripts/Pool
В PoolManager возвращает тип PoolObject. Хотелось бы, что бы можно было возвращать любые типы.